# Ruby Cyphering Leads to non Alphanumeric Characters

Tags: ruby, caesar-cipher

I'm trying to make a basic cipher.

```
def caesar_crypto_encode(text, shift)  
  (text.nil? or text.strip.empty? ) ? "" : text.gsub(/[a-zA-Z]/){ |cstr| 
  ((cstr.ord)+shift).chr }
end
```

but when the shift is too high I get these kinds of characters:

```
  Test.assert_equals(caesar_crypto_encode("Hello world!", 127), "eBIIL TLOIA!")

  Expected: "eBIIL TLOIA!", instead got: "\xC7\xE4\xEB\xEB\xEE \xF6\xEE\xF1\xEB\xE3!"
```

What is this format?

Comment: I'm still curious about that format though...

Comment: These are often better implemented with a simple mapping table and [`tr`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-tr) where there's no chance of introducing busted characters. The `chr` function makes no guarantees about output validity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you get the verbose output is because Ruby is running with UTF-8 encoding, and your conversion has just produced gibberish characters (an invalid character sequence under UTF-8 encoding).

ASCII characters `A-Z` are represented by decimal numbers (ordinals) 65-90, and `a-z` is 97-122. When you add 127 you push all the characters into 8-bit space, which makes them unrecognizable for proper UTF-8 encoding.

That's why Ruby `inspect` outputs the encoded strings in quoted form, which shows each character as its hexadecimal number `"\xC7..."`.

If you want to get some semblance of characters out of this, you could re-encode the gibberish into ISO8859-1, which supports 8-bit characters.

Here's what you get if you do that:

```
s = "\xC7\xE4\xEB\xEB\xEE \xF6\xEE\xF1\xEB\xE3!"
>> s.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>

# Re-encode as ISO8859-1.
# Your terminal (and Ruby) is using UTF-8, so Ruby will refuse to print these yet.
>> s.force_encoding('iso8859-1')
=> "\xC7\xE4\xEB\xEB\xEE \xF6\xEE\xF1\xEB\xE3!"

# In order to be able to print ISO8859-1 on an UTF-8 terminal, you have to 
# convert them back to UTF-8 by re-encoding. This way your terminal (and Ruby)
# can display the ISO8859-1 8-bit characters using UTF-8 encoding:
>> s.encode('UTF-8')
=> "Çäëëî öîñëã!"

# Another way is just to repack the bytes into UTF-8:
>> s.bytes.pack('U*')
=> "Çäëëî öîñëã!"
```

Of course the proper way to do this, is not to let the numbers overflow into 8-bit space under any circumstance. Your encryption algorithm has a bug, and you need to ensure that the output is in the 7-bit ASCII range.

**A better solution**

Like @tadman suggested, you could use `tr` instead:

```
AZ_SEQUENCE = *'A'..'Z' + *'a'..'z'

"Hello world!".tr(AZ_SEQUENCE.join, AZ_SEQUENCE.rotate(127).join)
=> "eBIIL tLOIA!
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm still curious about that format though...

Those characters represent the corresponding ASCII encoding after getting the ordinal (`ord`) of each letter and adding `127` to it (i.e. `(cstr.ord)+shift).chr`)

Why? Check [Integer#chr](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-chr), from the docs:

> Returns a string containing the character represented by the int's
>   value according to encoding.

So, for example, take your first letter "H":

```
char_ord = "H".ord
#=> 72

new_char_ord = char_ord + 127
#=> 199

new_char_ord.chr
#=> "\xC7"
```

So, `199` corresponds to `"\xC7"`. Keep changing all characters in `"Hello world"` and you will get `"\xC7\xE4\xEB\xEB\xEE \xF6\xEE\xF1\xEB\xE3"`.

To avoid this you need to loop only with `ord` values that represent a letter (answer in the *Possible duplicate* link).